# How to include failed screenshots into the codeception report

Tags: codeception

Just started using codeception 2.0.9 and have installed it with phantomjs and got some sample tests running.

Codeception gives a concise html report at the end that summarises passed tests in red and green, which is nice.
In the reporting directory there is also a screenshot of failed tests, e.g. ExampleCest.CheckLabel.fail.png ExampleCest.CheckLabel.fail.html

Question, how can these be (automatically) linked into report.html so that one can see the failed screenshots from the report in the browser?

Comment: I'd like to know any references on how the HTML report is generated, or how to control it.

Comment: I have been going through something similar (codeception + phantomjs + reports) and am curious if request functionality exists or if anyone is working on it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a enhancement (#3602) to include screenshot in the report, but it's not release in the current version (2.2).

[image: HTML report to include screenshots of failures from WebDriver]

You can check this feature status at https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/pull/3602.